# Run a macro in another file Application.run

Tags: excel, vba

This is the problem I have:
Two file opened, File1 and File2. On file 2 are experimental results of a cyclic test. I have a macro on File1 to analyse them, but if the macro run on File1 and search what I need on File2 and copy it in File1 it takes really a lot of time.
If I copy the macro on File2 and let it write the results I need on File2 it takes few seconds.
Now my idea is to open File2 from File1 like it was, let a macro run there, make there a Table with my results, copy the results on File1.
I've read that I should use Application.Run but somehow it is not working,

```
Dim book As Excel.Workbook          
Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(file2) 
book.Application.Run "file1.xls!probef5"
```

Is it correct if I'd like to say that the macro "probef5" of File1 should run on File2? The macro still try to run on File1…
or do I have better solution to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the internal project name; I use it all the time.

```
Application.Run "projekt_name.procedure"
```

[image]

You can see this in the above image.

Comment: what do you mean with internal project? How do I say that my macro of File1  (probef5 in the example above) has to run on the other opened file called "book"?

Comment: Before the point is indicated the excel file where the macro has to run, and after the point the name of the maco. I need the exclamation mark between the file and the macro, otherwise i get the error that the macro cannot be found. How do I indicate that file1 is not the file but a string with it inside?

Comment: Do you looked inside immage i attached?

Comment: ouchh I didn't seen it. However, the macro I call with Application.run, run still on the "file1". How do I say in the statement you posted that it has to run in the other file? Thank you in advance...

Comment: I do not know what you wanna say "file1" You should use  VBAProject or changed name.